# Select option with a submit button displaying info

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not really sure how to do this, but I'm looking at people selecting a person and finding info about them.

As in, if they choose Mary, and click submit, it will load a line of text under it saying info about Mary.

This is what I have so far. I've tried to look it up and cant seem to find anything and I'm not sure how to attack this problem.

```
Who is who connected to?<br>
<select>
  <option value="rkelly">R-Kelly</option>
  <option value="gwendolyn">Gwendolyn</option>
  <option value="mary">Mary</option>
  <option value="rufus">Rufus</option>
  <option value="chuck">Chuck</option>
  <option value="james">James (Cop)</option>
  <option value="bridget">Bridget</option>
  <option value="midget">Midget</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use javascript or ajax if you want it to be displayed without a page reload. It is unclear how you are willing to provide this info though.

Comment: Learn about DOM manipulation and event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML.

Comment: Well im looking at this, so if i click r-kelly, and click submit, as soon as i click submit below the dropdown and submit button it will display a bit of info on the person selected.

Comment: Where is that information stored? Are you using some kind of server-side technology (java, PHP, ruby)?